# Ubuntu 12.10 is slow and some programs gose to non-respond state

Tags: performance

Ubuntu 12.10 is so slow and a lot of not responding applications I was using Skype whenever i open it it will go to non-responding state thin back to normal after a while even the software centre the system process is eating the CPU I don’t know if the compiz is the problem but issuing the command compiz --replace restore the applications from non-responding state CPU : Intel Celeron D 3.4 RAM : 1 GB VGA : Intel G45 
Plz help

Comment: It's not that 'Ubuntu is slow'. Something is special with your computer hardware that makes Ubuntu not perform optimally.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing Gnome Shell or KDE Plasma?  Unity runs like a dog for me on 12.10 (ran fine on 12.04) but the other desktops ran fine.  I'm leaning towards Gnome Shell at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your video card doesn't support Ubuntu 12.10 ,I had the same problem with my asus k50c 1.500 Mhz 2 gb ram video card sis vga 771/671 when I made the upgrade to 12.10 and the upgrade worked fine , my applications  all got to slow down so I return to 12.04 and I can advise U to do the same thing ,because unfortunately these are old video cards so U can not pretend to much from it.

Comment: Your graphics card (SiS) does not support 3D hardware acceleration, so Ubuntu 12.10 uses LLVM (instead of Unity 2D) for graphics support. LLVM makes heavy use of the CPU for graphics support, and indeed may not be responsive. It was a good idea to return to 12.04 (Unity 2D).